# getpgid(child_pid) gets parent's pid/gid not child's gid

Tags: c, system

I am looking to get child's group id from the parent to store it in a job struct. When I use getpgid(child's_pid), I get the parent's pid/gid. Everything else is working fine except the group id. My understanding of pids and pgids is probably wrong but am not sure where.

My Code:

```
if ((newJob->pid = Fork()) == 0)
{
    
    if (setpgid(0, 0) == -1)
    {
        perror("setpgid() error");
    }
    printf("fork pid: %d\n", getpid());
    printf("fork gid: %d\n", getpgrp());
    execve(command, customArgv, NULL);
}

printf("parent pid: %d\n", getpid());
printf("parent gid: %d\n", getpgrp());
printf("fork pid from parent: %d\n", newJob->pid);
printf("fork gid from parent: %d\n", getpgid(newJob->pid));
```

Output:

```
parent pid: 2631063
parent gid: 2631063
fork pid from parent: 2631093
fork gid from parent: 2631063
fork pid: 2631093
fork gid: 2631093
```

Comment: The parents use of `getpgid()` is probably executing before the child's `setpgid()`.

Comment: that was it! I had a sleep(3); after the if and it didn't work before but it does now. interesting! Is there a way to make sure the child's setpgid() happens before parent's getpgid()?

Comment: You could use any of a (large) number of inter-process synchronization mechanisms.  There are lots to choose from.